# How can I assess .fulfilled action of loginUserSlice extraReducers in updateProfileSlice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to access just .fulfilled part of loginUserSlice in updateProfilSlice but unable to find a way to do so. I have tried to export it but it did not work. I have tried to call login function but that initiats all the extraReducers actions whereas I just want the functionality of login.fulfilled

**loginUserSlice.js**

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

export const login = createAsyncThunk(
  'loginUser',
  async ({ email, password }, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      
      const config = {
        headers: {
          // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      };
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        `/api/users/login`,
        { email, password },
        config
      );
      localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      const newError =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(newError);
    }
  }
);

const initialState = {};

export const loginUserSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'userLoginReducer',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logout: (state, action) => {
      localStorage.removeItem('userInfo');
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [login.pending]: () => {
      return {
        loading: true,
      };
    },

    [login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      return {
        loading: false,
        userInfo: action.payload,
      };
    },

    [login.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    },
  },
});
console.log(loginUserSlice.extraReducers);
export const { logout } = loginUserSlice.actions;
export default loginUserSlice.reducer;
```

**updateProfileSlice.js**

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';
import { login } from './loginUserSlice';


export const updateUserProfile = createAsyncThunk(
  'updateUserProfile',
  async (user, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const {
        userLogin: { userInfo }, 
      } = thunkAPI.getState();
      
      const config = {
        headers: {
          // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
        },
      };
      const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/users/profile`, user, config);
      thunkAPI.dispatch(login());
      localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      const newError =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(newError);
    }
  }
);

const initialState = {};

export const updateProfileSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'userLoginReducer',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_RESET: () => {
      return {};
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [updateUserProfile.pending]: (state) => {
      return {
        loading: true,
      };
    },

    [updateUserProfile.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      return {
        loading: false,
        success: true,
        userInfo: action.payload,
      };
    },

    [updateUserProfile.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    },
  },
});
export const { USER_UPDATE_PROFILE_RESET } = updateProfileSlice.actions;
export default updateProfileSlice.reducer;
```